# Pass css file into PDFMake styles

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, pdfmake

I'm currently trying to print a string containing HTML markup to pdf using the HTML-to-pdfmake and pdf make libraries. The HTML contains a lot of classes and ids and I have styling for those in a CSS file. Is there a way to pass that CSS file to the `styles` attribute in pdfmake instead of writing all the styles in the content definition section?

This is what I currently have:

```
   let documentDefinition = {
    pageSize: "A4",
    pageOrientation: "portrait",
    footer: footer,
    header: header,
    content: [
      {
        text: htmlToPdfmake(documentBody, {
          window: window,
        }),
      },
    ],
    styles: {
      header: {
        fontSize: 22,
        bold: true,
      },
      anotherStyle: {
        italics: true,
        alignment: "right",
      },
    },
  }
```

The goal would be to reference these styles from a css instead as I have a 1000 lines long css styling. So would be something like this:

```
   let documentDefinition = {
    pageSize: "A4",
    pageOrientation: "portrait",
    footer: footer,
    header: header,
    content: [
      {
        text: htmlToPdfmake(documentBody, {
          window: window,
        }),
      },
    ],
    styles: {
      path: "./styles/style.css"

    }
     
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI: [pdfmake style's are not CSS](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/1277#issuecomment-364122327) and the html-to-pdfmake module only [supports a limited set of CSS properties](https://github.com/Aymkdn/html-to-pdfmake#css-properties-supported).

> CSS can create very complex design, however this framework can only handle the most simple HTML / CSS. The support of CSS style is limited and might not work in all cases with all values:

Having said that, if you want to externalize this part of your configuration you can move it to a different JS (or even JSON) file and load it using your favorite module loader, as you would with any regular JS or JSON file.

Comment: You're welcome! HTML to PDF is a challenging use case, since HTML isn't really designed for print media. If you're trying to make an existing website printable your best bet is to create print-friendly CSS and then use a library like `html-pdf-node` to generate the PDF. Libraries like these use a headless version of Chrome to render and print the content (the same as when you would visit the page in your Chrome browser, use the Print function and then select "Save as PDF").

Comment: I'm trying to find a library that supports printing html with complex css and provides support for dynamic headers and footers. By my understanding PDFMake also supports a very limited set of css attributes. Could it be a possible solution to only solve the dynamic header issue with pdfmake and print the pdf with another library like puppeteer or html-pdf-node?

Comment: By dynamic headers I mean I'd like to append chapter numbers next to the page number based on which chapter the user is reading for instance.

Comment: is their a way to print html string in pdfmake? I have already used this library

Comment: @Dzsonah I found a library based on PDFMake that support most of HTML and CSS tags. Look [here](https://github.com/Aymkdn/html-to-pdfmake)